# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x+y+xy)\log{(x+y+xy)}}{x+y}dxdy$?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to evaluate this integral: $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x+y+xy)\log{(x+y+xy)}}{x+y}dxdy.$$
It looks like this integral is symmetry with variables $x$ and $y$ but I can't find the way to exploit it.
I tried to use this:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x+y+xy)\log{(x+y+xy)}}{x+y}dxdy\\=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}2x\frac{(x+xy+x^2y)\log{(x+xy+x^2y)}}{x(1+y)}dxdy,$$ but still can't isolate $x$ and $y$.
I really need some advices here, thank you.

EDIT
After trying more, i end up with this:$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(xy)\log{(x+y+xy)}}{x+y}dxdy.$$ I cant process more, any advices, thank you.

Comment: I think you have one too many integral signs...

Comment: Sorry, edited, thank you.

Comment: CAS says: $-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{25}{9}+\frac{\pi ^2}{18}-2 \ln^2(2)+\frac{4 \ln (2)}{9}+\ln (27)$

Comment: Using the simmetry you point out, it might be interesting to develop the (second) integral in polar coordinates as $$2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{1/\cos\theta}\frac{\rho^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\log(\rho\cos\theta + \rho\sin\theta + \rho^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}d\rho d\theta$$

Answer (score 4):

Using the simmetry with respect to $y=x$, your second integral can be written using polar coordinates as follows.
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I &=& \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{xy\log(x+y+xy)}{x+y}dxdy=\\
&=&2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{1/\cos\theta}\frac{\rho^3\cos\theta\sin\theta\log(\rho\cos\theta + \rho\sin\theta + \rho^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)}{\rho\cos\theta+\rho\sin\theta}d\rho d\theta=\\
&=&2\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}\int_0^{1/\cos\theta}\rho^2\log(\rho\cos\theta + \rho \sin\theta + \rho^2 \cos\theta \sin\theta)d\rho d\theta.
\end{eqnarray}
Integrating by parts yields
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I
&=&2\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}\left\{\left[\frac{\rho^3}3\log(\rho\cos\theta + \rho \sin\theta + \rho^2 \cos\theta \sin\theta)\right]_0^{1/\cos\theta}\right.+\\
& &\left.-\frac13\int_0^{1/\cos\theta}\frac{\rho^2(\cos\theta+\sin\theta+2\rho\cos\theta\sin\theta)}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta+\rho\cos\theta\sin\theta}d\rho\right\}d\theta=\\
&=&2\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}\left\{\frac{\log(1+2\tan\theta)}{3\cos^3\theta}+\right.\\
& & -\frac13\int_0^{1/\cos\theta}\left(2\rho^2-\rho\frac{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta\sin\theta}+\frac{(\cos\theta+
\sin\theta)^2}{\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}+\right.\\
& &-\left.\left.\frac{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^3}{\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}\cdot\frac1{\cos\theta+\sin\theta+\rho\cos\theta\sin\theta}\right)d\rho\right\}d\theta=\\
&=&2\int_0^{\pi/4}\left[\frac13\cdot\frac{\sin\theta\log(1+2\tan\theta)}{\cos^2\theta(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}-\frac29\cdot \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta(\cos\theta +\sin\theta)}+\frac16\cdot\frac1{\cos^2\theta}+\right.\\
& &\left.-\frac13\cdot \frac{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}+\frac13\cdot\frac{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2}{\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}\cdot \log\left(\frac{\cos\theta+2\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}\right)\right]d\theta.
\end{eqnarray}
Grouping into three integrals and replacing $\tan \theta$ with $t$ gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I &=& \frac23\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{t\log(1+2t)}{1+t}dt}_{\mathcal I_1}+\frac13\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{1+t}dt}_{\mathcal I_2}+\\& &-\frac23\underbrace{\int_0^1\left[ \frac{1+t}t-\frac{(1+t)^2}{t^2}\log\left(\frac{1+2t}{1+t}\right)\right]dt}_{\mathcal I_3}.\tag{*}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
$\mathcal I_1$ can be computed as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_1 &=& \int_0^1 \frac{t \log(1+2t)}{1+t}dt=\\
&=&\int_0^1 \log(1+2t)dt -\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+2t)}{1+t}dt=\\
&=&\frac32\log 3 -1 -\int_0^1 \log(1+2t)d[\log(2+2t)]=\\
&=&\frac32\log 3 -1 -2\log3\log2+\int_0^1 \frac{\log[1+(1+2t)]}{1+2t}d(1+2t)=\\
&=&\frac32\log3 -1-2\log3\log2+[-\mbox{Li}_2(-1-2t)]_0^1=\\
&=&\frac32\log 3 -1 -2\log3\log2-\mbox{Li}_2(-3)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.
\end{eqnarray}
Trivially $\mathcal I_2 = 2\log2-1$.
When finding the primitive for $\mathcal I_3$ note that all the divergent terms $\log t$ cancel out. We are left with
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_3 &=& \int_0^1\left[1+\frac1 t-\frac{\log(1+2t)}{t^2}-\frac{2\log(1+2t)}{t} - \log(1+2t)\right.+\\
& &\left.+\frac{\log(1+t)}{t^2} + \frac{2\log(1+t)}{t} + \log(1+t)\right]dt=\\
&=&\left[t+\log t - 2\log t + \frac{(1+2t)\log(1+2t)}t+2\mbox{Li}_2(-2t)\right.+\\
& &-t\log(1+2t) - \frac12\log(1+2t) + t+\\
& &+\log t -\frac{(1+t)\log(1+t)}t-2\mbox{Li}_2(-t)+\\
& &\left. +(1+t)\log(1+t) - t\right]_0^1=\\
&=& 1+3\log3 +2\mbox{Li}_2(-2)-\log 3 -\frac12 \log 3+1+\\
& &-2\log2 -2\mbox{Li}_2(-1)+2\log 2 -1-2+1=\\
&=&\frac32\log3 +\frac{\pi^2}{6}+2\mbox{Li}_2(-2).
\end{eqnarray}
Plugging in these results into \eqref{1} completes the computation.